# Reduce bounds of expanded area for hover

Tags: html, css

Consider this contrived example. I have two divs, one of which grows to twice the size when you hover over it. When you move your mouse out of the edge of the expanded box, it returns to normal size.

Notably, it only returns to normal size once your mouse leaves the bounds of the expanded box. What I would like is for the box to go back to its normal size when your mouse leaves the bounds of the original size of the box.

I've been doing some reading of other questions and I think maybe pseudo elements are the way forward, but I can't figure it out. There are examples of maintaining the bounding box size when the element shrinks, but not when it expands.

```css
.left {
width:300px; float:left;
}

.right {
width:300px; float:right; background-color: red;
}

.right:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<br>
</br>
<div style="width:800px">
    <div class="left">foo</div>
    <div class="right">bar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the `div` you want to transform. Apply the `:hover` effect to a parent `div` wrapping the transforming `div`. Example:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.parentBox:hover .box {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parentBox">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

You can also make the box react to events by putting the event handlers on the box's parent, example on click:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.parentBox:hover .box {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parentBox" onclick="alert('You clicked the box!');">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great in my contrived example so I'm happy to accept it, but is there a way for me to achieve this effect while still being able to click? I see that pointer-events only has "auto" (allow all) and "none" (allow none), so maybe not. It'd be great to have it react this way for hover but allow clicks still. I'm using react, so maybe it could be accomplished with that / js?

Comment: @DanielPorteous You can put your event handlers on the parent, I've updated my answer above.